# Read the respiration data to Arduino serial console

Tags: arduino-uno, sensors, usb, spi, networking

Currently working with [ADS1292rShield](https://github.com/Protocentral/ADS1292rShield_Breakout) library.
Is there any way to read the value of the respiration and heart rate without using the Protocentral GUI. Printing DataPacketHeader to the console just results in corrupted ASCII.

```c
DataPacketHeader[9] = s32DaqVals[0];            // 4 bytes Respiration data
DataPacketHeader[10] = s32DaqVals[0]>>8;
DataPacketHeader[11] = s32DaqVals[0]>>16;
DataPacketHeader[12] = s32DaqVals[0]>>24; 

    for(i=0; i<15; i++) 
    {
      Serial.write(i);
      Serial.write(DataPacketHeader[i]);     // transmit the data over USB
    }
```

Here is the output below of the Arduino serial monitor, is there any way to make sense of the data or how it is converted to a readable integer on the GUI?

```
⸮ < 0 p s | ` r I @ @ 9     ⸮ ⸮ ⸮ ⸮ ⸮ ⸮ ⸮ ⸮ ⸮ ⸮ ⸮ ⸮ < 2 $ & O ` q ` 8 0 ! > ⸮ ⸮ ⸮ ⸮ ⸮  ! 8 ! | H a @  9 $  ! ⸮ 8 B x  ⸮ ⸮ ⸮ ⸮  y a ` p  f ⸮ ⸮ ⸮ ⸮ ⸮ 1 b N p ⸮ ⸮ ⸮ ⸮ ⸮ ⸮ ⸮ ⸮ " D ` ` ` p  
 ! ⸮ ⸮ ⸮ ⸮ ⸮ ⸮ ⸮ ⸮ ⸮ ⸮ ⸮ ⸮ ⸮ ⸮ ⸮ ⸮ 0 ⸮ ' # 3 @ O ` D B @ @ ! ⸮ ⸮ ⸮ ⸮ ⸮ 0    a F ⸮ ⸮ ⸮ ⸮ ⸮ ⸮ " x p $ 0 ⸮
```

[image]

Comment: examine the four bytes as a 32 bit number

Comment: @jsotola I don't think the printout is corrupted because it is displaying valid data when the USB serial data is sent to the Protocentral GUI. I will try to group together the 4 bytes as a 32 bit integer.

Comment: the GUI is created using processing .... https://processing.org/ ... you can examine the sketch code and you can even rewrite the code for your own use

Comment: You are not printing the data, you are writing it. That is a difference. The packet format is binary, so you cannot get human readable data by writing. And jsotola is probably right. The data most likely consists of a 4 byte value.